# How do I upgrade system gems on heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm running on a heroku bamboo-mri-1.9.2 stack and getting the following message when I push to heroku:  I'm stumped:

```
  Installing hoe (2.9.1) /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:170:in `install': hoe requires RubyGems version >= 1.4. Try 'gem update --system' to update RubyGems itself. (Gem::InstallError)
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/source.rb:95:in `install'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/installer.rb:55:in `block in run'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `block in each'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/installer.rb:44:in `run'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/installer.rb:8:in `install'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/cli.rb:225:in `install'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:246:in `dispatch'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:389:in `start'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/bin/bundle:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/bundle:19:in `<main>'
   FAILED: http://docs.heroku.com/bundler
```

any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe this would be better submitted as a support request to heroku itself.  I'm pretty sure you don't have access to update system gems on heroku, maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I would exclude the 'hoe' gem from what you send up to github.

```
group :test, :development do
  gem "hoe"
  # other gems you want to exclude from github
end
```

Then set in your heroku variables:

```
heroku config:add BUNDLE_WITHOUT="development:test"
```

Read More: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler

Comment: where exactly should one add the above code??? group :test, :development do gem "hoe" # other gems you want to exclude from github
end

Comment: This is a clever workaround for hoe, but it does not answer the initial question. :/

Answer (score 0):

Try using different versions of how:

```
hoe 2.10.0 
hoe 2.9.6 
hoe 2.9.5 
hoe 2.9.4 
hoe 2.9.3
```

Add those one at a time, bundle, and then push to heroku.